# Exporting to Collada: Physics don't get exported

Tags: export, physics, collada

I added basic rigidbody characteristics to a default sphere in Blender and exported it to Collada but the physics information isn't exporting.

How can I get the physics data to be exported along the geometry?

Thanks in advance.

I'm using Blender 2.68.4

**EDIT:**

As for Blender 2.68.4 there is no support for physics data to COLLADA :(

Althought it seems that there is already a patch to export physics:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Architecture/COLLADA

https://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=25601&group_id=9&atid=127

This patch was already accepted into upstream so maybe in a near version support for this is added :D

I will leave the question open to notify the ones that favorites this question once this functionality is added.

**IN THE MEANTIME:**

You can solve this issue by:

- Saving the scene with physics in Blender format (`.blend`)
- Importing the `.blend` file into [Unity Engine](http://unity3d.com/unity/download/) (free edition)
- Use the [Unity Collada Exporter](http://u3d.as/content/fl4re/collada-dae-exporter-1-3-0-for-unity-3-5-4-0-free-pro-/3cC) to get a fully **physics** functional COLLADA `.dae` file.

Credits to [Rémi Arnaud](http://news.turbulenz.com/post/47447794610/collada-to-unity-to-webgl-via-turbulenz).

Comment: **@gandalf3:** Thanks for your comment, unfortunately, what I want is to export the whole scene with its geometry, materials, etc and the models physics as well. How can I do that?

Comment: FYI (all readers), I'm guiding diosney into adding physics support to Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the motion generated by the rigid-body simulation (not the mass and other parameters), you can bake the simulation to keyframes.

There are two ways to do this:

**Method one:**
In the *Tool shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D view) *> Rigid body tools*, press *Bake to Keyframes*:

[image]

**Method two:**
Press *3D view > Header > Object > Animation > Bake action*:

[image]

Comment: **@gandalf3:** Thanks for your help, unfortunately, what I want is to export the whole scene with its geometry, materials, etc and the models physics as well. How can I do that?

Comment: **@gandalf3:** The final purpose is to use the scene to be imported in a game engine that supports Collada, but the .dae file exported by Blender doesn't have any physics information :(

Comment: @diosney AFAIK, the [COLLADA exporter](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Import/COLLADA) does not support exporting the physics data (mass, constraints, etc.). You can bake the simulation to a normal animation, (as in my answer) and then export, this will export the animation data as well as geometry. Material exporting is limited, see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Import/COLLADA).

Comment: I tested what you suggested but don't worked for me :(

Comment: @diosney How did it not work? (what happened?)

Comment: In the exported `.dae` there is no physics information. As you say, seems that the exporter doesn't support yet the physics data. Do you know how to report this kind of thing to Blender or how can I get the code for the exporter to see if I can help and add this functionality?

Comment: Oh, to address your question, when I import the .dae into the game engine, the physics data related to the model isn't getting loaded, since it was an animation what was created.

Comment: It seems that there is already a patch to export physics: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Architecture/COLLADA, https://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=25601&group_id=9&atid=127 that is already accepted into upstream so maybe in a near version support for this is added :D I will leave the question open to notify the ones that favorites this question once this functionality is added.